# Reading and writing to a txt file on the server, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, text, server-side, serverside-javascript

Is it possible to modify and read a text file that is stored on the server using Javascript? If so how can I do it?

Free web space does not let me use php so I'm trying to use txt as a database.

Comment: can you use node.js as your server with your free web space?

Comment: It seems I'm better off trying to find a better space.

Comment: See if your web space supports any other server sided language and/or components, like ASP, JSP, CF, CGI, Node.js, ...